# ALTER USER Authentication Options in MySQL

Tags: mysql

According to MySQL documentation on ALTER USER statement (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/alter-user.html), I want to try the following statement copied from that page (changed the host to '%' and the password as well):

```
ALTER USER 'jeffrey'@'%'
  IDENTIFIED WITH caching_sha2_password BY 'new_PASSWORD&12'
  PASSWORD EXPIRE INTERVAL 180 DAY
  FAILED_LOGIN_ATTEMPTS 3 PASSWORD_LOCK_TIME 2;
```

Here are the steps I took. First, created a user, database and grant permissions.

```
CREATE USER 'jeffrey'@'%'
  IDENTIFIED BY 'new_PASSWORD&11';
  
CREATE DATABASE TestDB;  
Use TestDB;
CREATE TABLE testtable (
col1 INT PRIMARY KEY,
col2 CHAR(10) 
);

GRANT ALL 
ON TestDB.* TO jeffrey;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

From MySQL Workbench, jeffrey can log in and run "SELECT * FROM TestDB.testtable;" without problem. Then I ran ALTER USER cited above. Workbench does ask for the new password and jeffrey can log in and run the SELECT statement without having to change the password, i.e., the option 'PASSWORD EXPIRE' does not work in that statement. Next, I ran the modified statement below:

```
ALTER USER 'jeffrey'@'%'
  IDENTIFIED WITH caching_sha2_password BY 'new_PASSWORD&13'
  PASSWORD EXPIRE;
```

MySQL Workbench then does prompt for the password change. It feels to me that the option 'FAILED_LOGIN_ATTEMPTS ' causes the problem. I also pasted the first statement into Workbench which generates error message in Query Editor window (see attached screenshot).

Can you please tell me why? I use MySQL version 8.0.34-0ubuntu0.22.04.1. The same thing happens in Windows. Thank you very much in advance.

[image]

I tried several times but still got the same issues.

Comment: Did you mean to write "MySQL workbench does **not** prompt for the password change"?

Comment: It does prompt for password change with only the 'Password EXPIRE' option

Comment: Were you expecting it to require a new password in the first example? You told MySQL that the password was valid for 180 days. Why would it require changing the password immediately?

Comment: Got it. Thanks Bill.